# Iterating laravel form that update rows in column based off value of adjoining column

Tags: php, sqlite, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a SQlite database with 50 states and I want to create an input for each of the 50 states. The input would update the individual states' "totals" in the database with the number input in it's text field. I have created a form which is about 110 lines long, but I am certain I could do this via iteration in blade templating. I just don't know how to make the form fields correspond to one particular state in the array of states.

The DB has an Eloquent model named Distributors and looks as follows:

```
ID   |  State  | Total
1    |  PA     |  0
```

I am pretty sure I could make this thing work if I created separate input values for all fields and used the

```
DB::table('distributors')->where('state', '==', 'PA')
->update(array('total' => 'Input::get('total')'));
```

But there has to be an easier, more automated way... any direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Pass all states into your view:

```php
$states = DB::table('distributors')->lists('state');

return view('whatev', compact('states'));
```

Then iterate over them in your view:

```html
@foreach ($states as $state)
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="{{ $state }}">Total for {{ $state }}:</label>
        <input type="text" id="{{ $state }}" name="totals[{{ $state }}]">
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Then loop over them to save them:

```php
foreach (Input::get('states') as $state => $total) {
    DB::table('distributors')->where('state', $state)->update(compact('total'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, youve helped me understand how to pass information like this into a view and use it.

Comment: Should I iterate that loop in my Controller? Or should I do that in the HTML doc as well? I am having routing issues using my controller.